# Dijkstra: camino entre dos nodos

Tags: python, algoritmos, teoría-de-grafos

Tengo un problema, estoy atascado en este punto; necesito encontrar el camino de vuelta para poder imprimirlo pero soy incapaz de sacar la solución.
En primer lugar se recorre el camino hasta alcanzar el nodo deseado por el camino más corto pero ahora, tengo que imprimir ese camino pero no sé como hacerlo sin poner los demás nodos también visitados pero que no forman parte del camino.

Estoy visitando los nodos y guardando los pesos para alcanzar el siguiente nodo, así hasta llegar al que deseo. Una vez alcanzado se detiene la búsqueda. Ahora bien, tengo que imprimir el camino es decir los nodos desde el primero hasta el deseado. No sé de que manera puedo hacer eso.

Entrada:
(la ultima fila representa el inicio y el fin)
9 14
0 1 4
0 7 8
1 2 8
1 7 11
2 3 7
2 5 4
2 8 2
3 4 9
3 5 14
4 5 10
5 6 2
6 7 1
6 8 6
7 8 7
0 4
salida:(camino)
0 7 6 5 4

```
def select_min(distances,visited):
   min_dist=float('inf')
   index=0
   for i in range(1,len(distances)):
       if not visited[i]and distances[i]<min_dist:
           min_dist=distances[i]
           index=i
   return index

def algoritmo(grafo,s,e):
   distances=[float('inf')]*len(grafo)
   visited=[False]*len(grafo)
   listaAdj=[0]*len(grafo)
   distances[s]=0
   visited[s]=True

   for ini, fin, valor in grafo[s]:
       distances[fin]=valor
   while  not visited[e] :
       nextNode= select_min(distances,visited)
       visited[nextNode]=True
       for ini, fin,valor in grafo[nextNode]:
           distances[fin]=min(distances[fin],distances[ini]+valor)

   return distances



grafo=[]
n, m = map(int, input().strip().split())
for i in range(n):
   grafo.append([])
for k in range(m):
   i, f, v=(input().strip().split())
   ini= int(i)
   fin=int(f)
   valor=int(v)

   grafo[ini].append((ini, fin, valor))
s, e = map(int, input().strip().split())

algoritmo(grafo,s,e)
```

Comment: ¿Cual camino? ¿Dónde está almacenado?

Comment: Ese es el problema, que no se como almacenar el camino, yo visito los nodos por la arista o aristas de menor ponderación y estos pesos se guardan. pero ahí me quedo. no se como hacer para solo meter en el camino los nodos que forman parte del camino mas pequeño por ejemplo una entrada seria :9 14
0 1 4
0 7 8
1 2 8
1 7 11
2 3 7
2 5 4
2 8 2
3 4 9
3 5 14
4 5 10
5 6 2
6 7 1
6 8 6
7 8 7
0 4 y la salida seria: 0 7 6 5 4

Comment: Sería más fácil que editaras la pregunta para indicar las líneas donde se agregan/eliminan nodos al camino. Así será más fácil completar lo que pides.

Comment: Graciaas por el consejo